# Wordpress Login & Register works in localhost but not in my server

Tags: wordpress, session, authentication, registration

I have a custom ajax implementation of the Login and Registration parts in a wordpress site I am building. Here is the link:  [Uploaded site](http://www.enrista.co.za/urbanthirst)

I use the wp signon function. It works perfectly fine in my localhost, but once i uploaded it to the server for testing, there seems to be something wrong and I guess the session variable is not getting set. Could somebody please help me out ? It authenticates properly though, wherein if I type in a wrong id and password , an error msg is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your wp-options table? Often when you create local and then upload the urls in your options table don't get changed and it can mess things up. Have you tried logging in without the cool UI you built, to see if it is your WP install or the UI that is causing this?

Here is something to try running on your database:

```
update wp_options set option_value=replace(option_value,'local.old', 'local.new');
update wp_posts set post_content=replace(post_content,'local.old', 'local.new');
update wp_posts set guid=replace(guid,'local.old', 'local.new');
```

Replace all the local.old with your old url (probably 'http://localhost') and all local.new with your new url (http://www.enrista.co.za/urbanthirst/ most likely).

You might need to query the wp_options table to find out what url it was using if you  aren't sure. To find out the old url, try this:

```
SELECT option_name FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl'
```

Changing that will often fix these issues, because WP will try to access the old website to login, if the urls aren't changed in the table.